# Correct way to get the most common name of all items in a Set using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, set

I am currently trying to find the best way to find the most common name from all items in a Set.

The object in a Set are Person objects:

```
public class Person {
     private String name;

     ...

     public String getName() {
          return name;
     }
}
```

In the method findMostCommonName, I want to find the most common name of all the Person objects in the given set.  Is there a Java 8 way to do that?

```
public String findMostCommonName(Set<Person> personSet) {

//Code here

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't really anything different in Java8 that would help you with that. What you do is first group input by `getName` with counting downstream collector, then loop over resulting map and look for a key with maximum entry value.

Comment: By the way, your question title is misleading: There is no most common item in Set, since a set will only contain unique items, meaning that each item is equally common.

Comment: A Set can only have unique objects, but your example makes no guarantee that two Persons with the same name are not considered identical according to `Person.equals(...)`.

Comment: That's not true. It's a set of `Person` not `String`. So he can have multiple different person objects all with the same name, depending on his `equals` method

Comment: What are your `equals` and `hashCode` (and `toString`) implementations for `Person`?

Comment: What if multiple names tie for most common?

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg That's what I meant, since we don't know what his `equals` implementation was, the condition for equality is left ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
public String findMostCommonName(Set<Person> personSet) {
    return personSet.stream().map(Person::getName)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .orElse(null);
}
```

`personSet.stream().map(Person::getName)` straight-forwardly creates a stream of name strings, `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))` counts the number of occurences into a `Map<String,Long>`, then `.entrySet().stream()` will stream over the entries and `.max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).map(Map.Entry::getKey)` will find the entry with the highest value, i.e. count, and extract the key, which is the string with that count.

The last `.orElse(null)` determines how to handle the situation when there is no result, i.e. `personSet` is empty. If you use `get()` instead, a `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown in that case.

In case of a tie, an arbitrary name out of the names with the highest number of occurrences will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested loop and go over the collection using equals method to compare the names, if it returns true add +1 to a counter and keep the name with more occurrences, or you can use a key/value object like a HashMap and store the number of times each name appears

Answer (score 0):

```
public String findMostCommonName(Set<Person> personSet) {
    return personSet.stream().parallel().map(Person::getName)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream().parallel()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .orElse(null);
}
```

> Just added Parallelism to speed up the code by around 1.2x